# Slow AD properties retrieval in C#

Tags: c#, vbscript, active-directory

Hi all I'm porting over my VBScript over to C#. And I ran into a problem that Active Directory properties retrieval is much slower in C#.

This is my incomplete C# code

```
foreach(string s in dictLast.Keys)
{
    if(s.Contains("/"))
        str = s.Insert(s.IndexOf('/'), "\\");
    else
        str = s;
    dEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + str);
    strUAC = dEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value.ToString();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [NOW](readTime) VALUES(\"" + test.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString() + "\")";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    test.Reset();
    test.Start();
}
```

If I comment out this line.
strUAC = dEntry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value.ToString();

It runs at 11 secs. But if I don't, it runs at 2mins 35 secs. The number of records are 3700. On average each record runs at 50 secs. I'm using the Stopwatch Class.

My VBscript runs at only 39 secs (Using difference of Time). With each record either a 0 or 15 milliseconds. I'm using the difference of Timer().

Here's my VBscript

```
strAttributes = "displayName, pwdLastSet, whenCreated, whenChanged, userAccountControl"
For Each strUser In objList.Keys
    prevTime = Timer()
    strFilter = "(sAMAccountName=" & strUser & ")"
    strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"
    adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
    Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute
    On Error Resume Next   
    If (adoRecordset.Fields("displayName") = null) Then
        strCN = "-"
    Else
        strCN   = adoRecordset.Fields("displayName")
    End If
    If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
        MsgBox(strUser)
    End If
    strCr8  = DateAdd("h", 8, adoRecordset.Fields("whenCreated"))
    strUAC  = adoRecordset.Fields("userAccountControl")
    If (strUAC AND ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD) Then
        strPW = "Never expires"
    Else
        If (TypeName(adoRecordset.Fields("pwdLastSet").Value) = "Object") Then
            Set objDate = adoRecordset.Fields("pwdLastSet").Value
            dtmPwdLastSet = Integer8Date(objDate, lngBias)
        Else
            dtmPwdLastSet = #1/1/1601#          
        End If
        If (dtmPwdLastSet = #1/1/1601#) Then
            strPW = "Must Change at Next Logon"
        Else
            strPW = DateAdd("d", sngMaxPwdAge, dtmPwdLastSet)
        End If
    End If
    retTime = Timer() - prevTime
    If (objList.Item(strUser) = #1/1/1601#) Then
        Wscript.Echo strCN & ";" & strUser & ";" & strPW & ";" & strCr8 & ";" & ObjChange.Item(strUser) & ";0;" & strUAC & ";" & retTime
    Else
        Wscript.Echo strCN & ";" & strUser & ";" & strPW & ";" & strCr8 & ";" & ObjChange.Item(strUser) & ";" & objList.Item(strUser) & ";" & strUAC & ";" & retTime
    End If
Next
```

Any ideas what's the problem?
Please tell me if I'm not giving enough information. Thank you.

DirectorySearcher way. 1 min 8 secs.

```
dEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + strDNSDomain);
string[] strAttr = {"userAccountControl"};
foreach(string s in dictLast.Keys)
{
    if(s.Contains("/"))
        str = s.Insert(s.IndexOf('/'), "\\");
    else
        str = s;
    ds = new DirectorySearcher(de, "(sAMAccountName=" + s + ")", strAttr, SearchScope.Subtree);
    ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userAccountControl");
    SearchResult rs = ds.FindOne();
    strUAC = rs.Properties["userAccountControl"][0].ToString();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [NOW](readTime) VALUES(\"" + test.Elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString() + "\")";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    test.Reset();
    test.Start();
}
```

where strDNSDomain is the defaultNamingContext. I've tried with domain name but it runs worse, at 3 mins 30 secs.

Looking at someone else's code. Would there be a difference if we omit the domain part?

```
using (var LDAPConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://domain/dc=domain,dc=com", "username", "password"))
```

And just use "LDAP://dc=domain,dc=com" instead.

Work around. Instead of binding each user and getting the properties. I stored all the properties in the first search for lastLogon instead. And output using StreamWriter.

Comment: Your DirectorySearcher code should work.  I will try to run similar test on my test domain tonight.  One thing that I need from you is the `strBase` you used in VBscript.  It should be the same as your C# code.  Also, how many doomain controllers and sites do you have?  It sounds like you are accessing a remote site domain controller.

Comment: @user607455 To sum up, you have 15ms per record by vbscript. You have 14.6 ms per record by C#.  You need to be careful that Timer() used in VBScript has a precision up to 10-15ms only.  Stopwatch in C# is using high frequency clock which has much higher resolution and accurate.  The fact that you saw 0 or 15 ms in VBscript is just because the Timer doesn't have enough precision for you.  A fair comparison would be to compare their total time running across all 3400 records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `DirectoryEntry` and `ADOConnection` use ADSI underlying.  There shouldn't be any performance difference.

The only reason for the performance difference is that you are trying to retrieve two different sets of data.

In your VBScript, you are setting ""displayName, pwdLastSet, whenCreated, whenChanged, userAccountControl" to `strAttributes`.  ADSI is going to load these five attributes back from AD only.

In your C# code, you didn't call the [RefreshCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y73eyaya.aspx) method to specify what attributes that you like to load.  So, when you access `DirectoryEntry.Properties`, it automatically calls a `RefreshCache()` for you without passing in any attributes for you.  By default, ADSI will return all non-constructed attributes to you (pretty much all attributes) if you don't specify what attributes to load.

Another problem is that in your VBscript, you run only one LDAP query while in your C# code, you are running many LDAP queries.  Each of the DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache() is going to translate to one single LDAP query.  So, if you are trying to access 1000 objects, you are going to run 1000 different LDAP queries.

Take a relational database analogy, in VBscript, you are running

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLE
```

In C# code, you are running multiple times of the following queries

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLE WHERE id = @id
```

Of course, the C# code will be slower.

To do similar thing in C# code, you should use [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) instead of [DirectoryEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx).

Similarly, you need to remember to specify [DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload.aspx) in order to specify what attributes to return from a LDAP query.  If you don't specify, it will return all non-constructed attributes to you again.

Comment: strAttributes = "displayName, pwdLastSet, whenCreated, whenChanged, userAccountControl" Ok I got another problem now. How do I go next line? By pressing Enter it will Save Edits instead.

Comment: @user607455 I also ran into this problem when I used StackOverflow first time.  I don't have a solution but you can post a question to meta.stackoverflow.com  Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: @user607455 Try calling the RefreshCache with the same set if attributes.

Comment: @user607455 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form You don't need to ask.  Somebody asked it before :)

Comment: Thanks. I thought Properties["userAccountControl"] is already specifying an attribute.

Much faster. Total of 1 min 12 secs. An average of 14.6 millisecs per record.

I've added this 2 lines of code.

string[] strAttr = {"userAccountControl"};
dEntry.RefreshCache(strAttr);

But the timing is still nowhere near the VBScript's speed. Is this the fastest C# can go. Or is it an optimisation problem?

What's the point of going next line if the comments still doesn't show it.

Comment: @user607455 Sorry, I didn't read through your code carefully.  You are still not comparing apple to apple.  In the VBscript code, you are doing subtree search.  In C#, you are using DirectoryEntry, which is doing base scope search and you are accessing the LDAP searcher many times.  To do the same thing, you should use `DirectorySearcher`.  I am going to have dinner now.  Note that similar to DirectoryEntry, you need to specify PropertiesToLoad to make sure you only load the attributes that you feel interested.  I am going to have dinner now.  I will update my answer after my dinner :)

Comment: I've already tried the DirectorySearcher way before posting here. Wouldn't a direct binding be faster than a search? The speed is comparable, if not slower to using DirectoryEntry without refreshing the cache. I did a subtree search in VBScript as I was still new at that time. I thought that the only way to get an object was through a search. Didn't know that you could directly bind it to an object through DN. Might be I didn't optimise my searcher properly. See answer below.

Comment: @user607455 Post your `DirectorySearcher` code here.  The thing that you are seeing DirectorySearcher slower should be because you didn't specify `PropertiesToLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of things you can do

1. Enable Audit log in the LDAP server and see how your requests are going through. Audit logs will show you how much time it is taking for each request from your application and how many connections are opened etc.
2. Use System.DirectoryServices.Protocols which can make Asynchronous calls to LDAP. Check this [sample post](http://dunnry.com/blog/2006/10/31/AsynchronousLDAPSearchingWithSystemDirectoryServicesProtocols.aspx). Another advantage of using this name space is that you can specify attributes.
3. Close connection properly.

Answer (score 1):

use DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad to load only required properties instead of all properties.

what i see from vbscript following is a bit closer .. copying from some project, kindly test

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("ldap://domainname");
                    DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher();
                    deSearch.SearchRoot = de;
                    deSearch.Filter = "(&(ObjectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName="+strUser+"))";
                    deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
                    deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdLastSet");
                    deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("whenCreated");
                    deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("whenChanged");
                    deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userAccountControl);


                    deSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                    SearchResult sr = deSearch.FindOne();
```

Comment: What DirectoryEntry should I bind to? And what search filter would be the fastest?

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to read the property:

```
If searchResult.Properties.Contains(PropertyName) Then
        Return searchResult.Properties(PropertyName)(0).ToString()
    Else
        Return String.Empty
End If
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed the code markdown, each line must be prefixed with 4 spaces.  Please explain why or how this works.